# Passing shared memory object between two processes via socket in Python

Tags: python, sockets, multiprocessing, shared-memory

My application consists of two Python processes connected by the means of a TCP socket. The first process is designed to read files and put them in shared memory rather than push down the socket, so that the other process could read them.

```
import os
import zmq
import mmap
import time
import ctypes
import pickle
import dill
import tempfile
import multiprocessing as mp

MEETING_POINT = 'tcp://127.0.0.1:12345'
FILEFD, FILEPATH = tempfile.mkstemp()


def run_server():
    Server().run()


def read_file():
    return open(FILEPATH, 'r').read()


class Client(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ctx = zmq.Context()
        self.socket = self.ctx.socket(zmq.DEALER)
        self.socket.connect(MEETING_POINT)

    def cleanup(self):
        self.socket.close()
        self.ctx.term()

    def run(self):
        self.socket.send(dill.dumps(read_file()))


class Server(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ctx = zmq.Context()
        self.socket = self.ctx.socket(zmq.DEALER)
        self.socket.bind(MEETING_POINT)

    def cleanup(self):
        self.socket.close()
        self.ctx.term()

    def run(self):
        f = dill.loads(self.socket.recv())
        print(f)


def main():
    with open(FILEPATH, 'w') as fd:
        fd.write('blah')

    mp.Process(target=run_server).start()
    time.sleep(.5)  # a (poor, but tolerable) alternative to handshaking
    Client().run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My question boils down to this: how do I pass information about the segment of memory, that the second process is to access, through the socket? I've tried the following (with both `pickle` and `dill`), all to no avail:

- use `mmap.mmap` on a file directly or to store its contents. Result: `TypeError: Required argument 'fileno' (pos 1) not found` when unpickling on the server side.
- use multiprocessing.Array:

  `with open(FILEPATH, 'r') as fd:
      contents = bytearray(fd.read())
      arr = mp.Array(ctypes.c_byte, contents, lock=False)`

Result: `pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'multiprocessing.sharedctypes.c_byte_Array_4'>: it's not found as multiprocessing.sharedctypes.c_byte_Array_4` when pickling on the client side.

I am convinced there's a simpler (and working) way to do this, is there? I can't pre-read all the necessary files and pack them into a `multiprocessing.Array` to pass as `args` when creating a server process, of course that would (supposedly) solve everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question because I figured what **exactly** I were to do. According to `man mmap`, for the second process to be able to read the first one's memory it is sufficient to create a memory segment with `MAP_SHARED` flag. Therefore, as in `mmap.mmap`'s constructor this flag is set by default, all one has to do is pass the file name and not a class instance:

```
# sometime during the first process' execution
fd = open(filepath_to_process, 'w')
memory = mmap.mmap(fd.fileno(), 0)
socket.send(filepath_to_process)

# on the other side of socket, this happens:
unprocessed_filepath = socket.recv()
fresh_fd = open(unprocessed_filepath, 'r')
mm = mmap.mmap(fresh_fd.fileno(), 0)

# voilà! All the changes are now propagated to the second process
```

Of course, access modes for a file and a memory region have to match, but there's a separate section in `man mmap` for that, called **"ERRORS"**.

As for the shared memory, there are [`posix_ipc`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/posix_ipc) and [`sysv_ipc`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sysv_ipc) modules (the latter supports a wider variety of OSes).